# Discordbot TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python, discord.py

Im new to python and tryin to make a discord bot and I got this `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str` when the bot send message show 'song name' searched by name instead of url and dont know how to fix it, when i use url it work fine

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx, *, url):
  if (ctx.author.voice):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
      await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
      voice = await channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.send('`You are not in a voice channel`')

  YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True', 'default_search':"ytsearch"}
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
  voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
  with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      if 'entries' in info:
        url = info["entries"][0]["formats"][0]['url']
      elif 'formats' in info:
          url = info["formats"][0]['url']
  if not voice.is_playing():
      voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda x=0: check_queue(ctx, ctx.message.guild.id))

      embed_p = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.magenta())
      embed_p.add_field(name='Playing:『  ' + info.get('title')+' 』', value='『'+ctx.author.mention+'』' , inline=False)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed_p)
```

Comment: `name='Playing:『  ' + info.get('title')+' 』', value='『'+ctx.author.mention+'』`. Try wrapping the variables in str() to cast them, see if that helps. Considering those are the only times you concatenate its also due to one of them not being a string type.

Comment: I change it to ``name='Playing:『  ' + str(info.get('title'))+' 』`` the bot message ``Playing:『  None 』``

Comment: And that makes sense, that means that you were never getting a string, but rather None back. Could you log 'info' before you create the embed and share it with me?

Comment: I just start learn python for a while and dont know how to log'info'

Comment: No worries. All you need to do is just `print(info)`. Whether you're in an IDE like Visual studio code, or an online IDE like Replit, they both display it in the terminal/console.

Comment: after I print(info) It show a really really long text https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VGYzYg58WPMW1-a7wbK9r-Pk_Xme7AyJ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109116501900966208683&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: i'll add an answer and explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the data structure of what you're trying to access in the future when wanting to use data from inside of them. The info variable you logged look like this:

```
   "_type":"playlist",
   "entries":[
      {
         "id":"dQw4w9WgXcQ",
         "title":"Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Official Music Video)",
         "formats":[
            {
               "asr":48000,
               "filesize":1232413,
               "format_id":"249",
               .....
```

And continues for a long time.

Now if you try and access title from `info`, you got None because title does not exist in `info`. However, if you go deeper into the object you can see that there is a

`"title":"Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Official Music Video)"`

To access this, you want to first access `info`, then `entries`, which is an array which can be seen in the formatsnippet I provided above. Then you can access the first object in entries which holds title.

Replace `info.get('title')` with `info['entries'][0]['title']`

Comment: No problem, dont forget to mark it as an answer if it helped you! Have a great day.